# Import targets during build process with MSBuild

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, msbuild, vcpkg

I am using [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) as package manager with Visual Studio C++ project. I have created initial target to basically set up vcpkg (clone vcpkg repo and download vcpkg.exe):

```
<Target Name="EnsureVcpkgBuild" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <Exec Command="git clone $(VcpkgRepo).git ..\packages\vcpkg" Condition="!Exists('..\packages\vcpkg\.git')" ContinueOnError="true" />
    <Exec Command="git --git-dir=..\packages\vcpkg\.git --work-tree=..\packages\vcpkg pull --ff-only" Condition="Exists('..\packages\vcpkg\.git')" ContinueOnError="true" />
    <Exec Command="..\packages\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat" Condition="!Exists('..\packages\vcpkg\vcpkg.exe')" ContinueOnError="true" />
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project uses vcpkg that is missing on this computer. Manually download from $(VcpkgRepo) and place the contents in {0}. Or install git and add it to your path, for more information see https://git-scm.com. The missing file is {1}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\vcpkg\vcpkg.exe')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\vcpkg\', '..\packages\vcpkg\vcpkg.exe'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\msbuild\vcpkg.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\vcpkg\', '..\packages\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\msbuild\vcpkg.targets'))" />
</Target>
```

In my project I am importing the vcpkg targets file:

```
<ImportGroup>
    <Import Project="..\packages\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\msbuild\vcpkg.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\msbuild\vcpkg.targets')" />
</ImportGroup>
```

This setup ensures build works smoothly in Visual Studio without any additional work. However when working with CI/CD pipeline I have to first invoke `EnsureVcpkgBuild` first before trying to build the project. Can I set up this project in such way that I don't have to invoke `EnsureVcpkgBuild` and initiating build automatically sets up vcpkg and imports `vcpkg.targets`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use nuget package to realize them all automatically.

What I think is that you wrote a target to download the reop project `vcpkg` into the local  and then manually import the core target from the dowloadeded `vcpkg` project.

It could be done easily on the local area but on the cl pipeline, it is not suitable.

So use nuget could be more easier.

Just install the nuget package [Vcpkg.Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Vcpkg.Nuget/1.5.0?_src=template) into your c++ project.

All the import targets are in the nuget package and it could be imported into your project  automatically with the installation of nuget.

When you are on the CI/CD pipeline, just add a [nuget restore task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/packages/nuget-restore?view=azure-devops) to restore the nuget packages on the pipeline.

Comment: That’s an interesting solution, and since I am already using nuget restore I can use this approach.

Comment: The Github page indicates that the project is not maintained anymore. Although, I have accepted your answer (cause only you answered), I would advise against using this. Vcpkg team seems to be working on integrating it with Visual Studio so in future I probably don't have to worry about this.